# Filter before manage_posts_custom_column

Tags: custom-post-types

I set up a custom table with custom posts type, in my case, I would like to show people from a specific club.
How can I filter before manage_posts_custom_column ?

```
<?php
    add_filter( 'manage_edit-gymnasts_columns', 'my_edit_gymnasts_columns', 9999 ) ;

    function my_edit_gymnasts_columns( $columns ) {
        $columns = array(
            'last_name' => __('Last name'),
            'first_name' => __('First name'),
            'birthday' => __('Birthday'),
            'club' => __('Last club'),
        );
        return $columns;
    }

add_action( 'manage_gymnasts_posts_custom_column', function ( $column_name, $post_id ) 
{
    $license = new license;
    // var_dump($license);

    if ( $column_name == 'last_name') {
        $last_name = get_post_meta($post_id, "gymnasts_last_name");
        echo('<a href="post.php?post='.$post_id.'&action=edit">'.$last_name[0].'</a>');
    }
    if ( $column_name == 'first_name') {
        $first_name = get_post_meta($post_id, "gymnasts_first_name");
        echo $first_name[0];
    }
    if ( $column_name == 'birthday') {
        $birthday = get_post_meta($post_id, "gymnasts_birthday");
        echo date_i18n('j F Y ', strtotime($birthday[0]));
        // echo $birthday[0];
    }
    if ( $column_name == 'club') {
        echo $license->GetFromGymnastId($post_id);
    }
}, 10, 2 );
```

Thx in advance ! :)

Comment: you create clubs as a taxinomy, you set `show_admin_column = TRUE` and then this column is generated with possibility of filter by club.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot use taxonomies, I would like to know how to display in the table only the results I want (based on a wp_query request for example).